# I can not do a POST: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm doing a WebAPI 2 with Entity Framework on a database in SQL Server. I have two tables, one called Usuarios that has an id as the primary key and a idTipoUsuario as a foreign key to the  table.

I have my Entity Data Model generated with the assistant connected to the database like this:

```
public partial class Usuarios
{
    public int idUsuario { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string apellido_p { get; set; }
    public string apellido_m { get; set; }
    public string usuario { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string contrasena { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dia_creacion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ultima_sesion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> idTipoUsuario { get; set; }

    public virtual TipoUsuario TipoUsuario { get; set; }
}

public partial class TipoUsuario
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public TipoUsuario()
    {
        this.Usuarios = new HashSet<Usuarios>();
    }

    public int idTipoUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Usuarios> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

In my UsuariosController I have added these lines of code:

```
 public class UsuariosController : ApiController
{
    private TestUsersEntities db = new TestUsersEntities();
    //GET api/Usuarios
    public IEnumerable<Usuarios> Get() {

        return db.Usuarios.ToList();
    }

    //GET api/Usuarios?idUsuario=1
    public Usuarios Get(int idUsuario) {
        return db.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(e => e.idUsuario == idUsuario);
    }

    //POST 
    public void Post([FromBody]Usuarios usuarios) {
        db.Usuarios.Add(usuarios);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The GET work perfectly, but when I want to do a POST using Postman, it throws me the error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity

In the Postman I put the script in the Test section like this: (and I do a POST to this address: http: // localhost: 53799 / api / Users)

```
{
"nombre":"Isaias",
"apellido_p":"Orozco",
"apellido_m":"Toledo",
"usuario":"isatol",
"email": "isatol@gmail.com",
"contrasena":"isa",
"dia_creacion": null,
"ultima_sesion": null,
"idTipoUsuario": 2
```

}

Then the user entity receives null.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Make sure you set the proper content type. You should also do some defensive coding, checking for null and you should also return `IHttpActionResult` derived class

Comment: which part of your code returns an error specifically

Comment: @VijunavVastivch here   db.Usuarios.Add(usuarios); The entity usuarios is null

Comment: @Nkosi the status is 400 Bad Request. i used InnerException and the result of the exception is 

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Message  "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: entity"

ParamName  "entity" 

Source  "EntityFramework"

Comment: I was making the requests wrong, thank you. it works now